# Java grammar on the strange ActionListener

Tags: java

I'm new to Java. I tried to look up on this grammar but could not find it. Could you please point out what this is?

```
class actions{
   ...
   public ActionListener WHATISTHIS = new ActionListener () {
      public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event) {
         String action = event.getActionCommand ();
         show_error ("Key unimplemented: " + action + ": "
                    + keys.valueOf (action).get_html ());
         refresh (action);
      }
   };
   ...
```

Is WHATISTHIS an object with type ActionListener? And the stuff {..} after new a junk of code for the object? I am confused. Normally I see something like:

```
[MODIFIER] [TYPE] obj = new [TYPE]();
```

But in the case above, it is:

```
[MODIFIER] [TYPE] obj = new [TYPE](){...};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This type of class is called [**anonymous class**](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/jnut/ch03_12.htm).

It declares and instantiates a class that implements `ActionListener`.

Answer (score 2):

```
public ActionListener WHATISTHIS = new ActionListener ()
```

is [Anonymous Inner class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/innerclasses.html) in java. 
It is instantiating a class which implements `ActionListener`. Anonymous Inner classes dont have any name. 
please have a look about it [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/innerclasses.html)